# Can not connect with Oracle Database

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle

I am using windows 7 32 bit machine. Now when i am trying to connect oracle on remote server from .net application i am getting following exception. What could be the issue? earlier this application was working fine. but after formatting the system i am getting this exception.

Please help immediately.

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.OCIEnvCreate(IntPtr& envhpp, MODE mode, IntPtr ctxp, IntPtr malocfp, IntPtr ralocfp, IntPtr mfreefp, UInt32 xtramemsz, IntPtr usrmempp)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.TracedNativeMethods.OCIEnvCreate(IntPtr& envhpp, MODE mode)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OciHandle..ctor(OciHandle parentHandle, HTYPE handleType, MODE ocimode, HANDLEFLAG handleflags)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString connectionOptions)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()
   at ArvindADMS.Program.UpdateLogRecord(DateTime dt, String attTime, String empNo, String action, String deviceId, Int32 checkinoutid)
```

Comment: You should use another proider, The Micorsoft provider has been deprecated for a long time: [Oracle and ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You probably use wrong provider. Long time ago there was disscussion on [MSDN about same exception](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2876c020-8db5-4d23-a70e-0825b7c036d9/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-violation?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

So change provider to OLE DB or use Microsoft Connector for Oracle by Attunity for SSIS